# How to dump raw serial data to disk

Tags: serial-port

How can I record all data coming out of a serial port straight to a file on disk?

I have tried `cat` and `cp`, but these appear to be buffered, and I am trying to log a small amount of data, so nothing comes through.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(stty raw; cat > received.log) < /dev/<your_serial_port>
```

Originally from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-redirect-serial-port-input-to-a-file-4920/).

Answer (score 3):

```
stdbuf -o0 cat /dev/ttyS0 >ttyS0.log
```

If MODE is '0' the corresponding stream will be unbuffered.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.html

Comment: Of all the answers found online, this was the only one that worked on a very fast serial (921000 baudrate). Thanks!